# Off canvas menu with fixed page content

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a fixed menu, I always want it at the top of my page:

```
.fixed-menu{
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: tomato;
}
```

I also want an off canvas menu.

The problem I am having is that when you open the off canvas menu, the fixed menu is no longer fixed.

After playing with the issue, it's something to do with 3d transform, but I cannot find a fix.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soq6uy5v/1/)

Comment: Perhaps you want to do something like this? http://codeply.com/go/7MoqqyDp7P

Comment: @Skelly sorry, no, the nav needs to move with the page when the off canvas menu pulls out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do with the "fixed menu"? It don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it this way, the page is essentially locked when the menu is open http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/hApKk

Basically wrapping the content and making it overflowY: scroll;

```
article {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not what im looking for.